# wrong date on conversion toISOString()

Tags: javascript, azure-cosmosdb

I am confused why on converting `8/20/2021` to ISO (cosmosDB format) I am getting `2021-08-19T18:30:00.000Z`

```
const event = new Date('8/20/2021');
console.log(event.toISOString()); //"2021-08-19T18:30:00.000Z"
```

all the date are saved as string in my cosmosdb and hence I was not able to filter based on given date range and as result we ended up converting string to Date but now when I am trying to convert in to cosmos db expected format it gives me incorrect or may be correct date to update my database.

should I go ahead and update  DB to `2021-08-19T18:30:00.000Z` in place of `8/20/2021`? or it should be `2021-08-20T00:00:00.000Z`?

Answer (score 0):

The value you are passing to `Date()` is vague. It's being parsed as a date for the timezone for the computer's locale.

When you convert to an ISO string, it's being displayed in UTC, which is 5 and a half hours behind that local time zone.

- Be more specific when you pass the string to `Date()`
- Consider converting the date to the user's local time zone when you read it back from the database

Comment: I am from india How can I convert these dates to american timezone, I am least bothered about the time but dates I want them to be same

Answer (score 0):

The `Date.parse()` method parses a string representation of a date, and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC

Try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

```
const event = Date.parse('8/20/2021');
console.log(event) // expected output: 818035920000
```

Now you can store that in your db.